# Quadro 600 display is VGA only - how to fix

Tags: drivers, 18.04, video, vga

Beginner at Linux. In the course of messing up and backing out of CUDA installs on my Ubuntu 18.04 system. My display set itself to VGA only.

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected primary 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480       73.00*
```

Under Software and Updates → Additional Drivers tab, I am using `nvidia-driver-390`.

Under System and Settings → Graphics, it shows:

> llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 128 bits)

How to fix the display driver?

Answer (score 0):

FIXED. Finally.

Somewhere along the way the nvidia drivers got blacklisted. I hand-commented out all lines in /lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf. Rebooted. Back to 1920x1200. xrandr now reports reasonable info.